# Question on crc32 -> 64 by multiplication

Tags: crc

Having a hash quickly accessible in a large database is a good thing, most hashes these days are much too large for that.
Best performance on a database is 32 bit int followed not too far off by 64 bit int keys but accessing a MD5 key already comes with a noticeable performance hit and requires (more than) twice the memory which matters when you have billions of rows.

Using CRC32 for hashing has a too high collision risk in my task but 64bit would be fine, however there is no nice native 64 bit hashing function available.

I wondered if I can just calculate two CRC32 hashes.
For example one hash of the string and one hash of the reversed string or with a couple bytes offset.
Then I multiply both 32 bit hashes with each other, which gives me up to 64 bit results.

Would that be an acceptable method to gain a proper 64 bit-ish hash from the 32 bit CRC function ?

Comment: CRCs are not cryptographically strong against deliberate collisions, thus this is hardly on-topic. The product of the question's two CRCs will likely give less protection against random collisions (at least of unrelated messages) than does their mere concatenation. Argument: with multiplication, 3/4 of the numbers reached will be even, and the 64-bit numbers having a prime factor larger than 32-bit will never be reached,

Comment: Use a variant of [Gimli](https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/lightweight-cryptography/round-2-candidates) hash function with capacity of 128-bit and a rate of 256-bit, truncated appropriately.

Comment: Why don't you just truncate any good hash function output to 64 bit ?

Comment: The reason for not truncating is how ugly that will make your SQL statements, it requires to cut and cast the hashing function.
I've used internal procedures as well as the above method, both comes with plenty downsides I don't like.

Comment: You can use two different polynomials.